# How can I burn a WIM image to DVD or to convert it to ISO?

Tags: conversion, dvd, burning, iso-image, wim

I need to run System Recovery in Vista, but its boot loader is destroyed. The only way to run System Recovery seems to be to burn a temporary DVD from the `base.wim` and `boot.wim` taken from Vista's recovery partition.

How can I do this without having any Vista installation or DVD? I can download anything, but only from legitimate sources (e.g. not torrents, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using [Microsofts Windows Automated Installation kit (WAIK)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en). There's a tutorial [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311(WS.10).aspx) how to go about creating a bootable dvd that you can use to repair your computer.